# Can members of one inner class can access another inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Suppose a class has two inner classes `inner_a` and `inner_b`, can one inner class can access another ? i.e, can states and methods of `inner_a` can be used in `inner_b`?

Comment: write some basic class with two inner classes and test it?

Comment: If two _outer_ classes cannot access each other's variables, then why would _inner_ classes be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes can access fields and methods of outer class but they cannot access fields and methods of each other.